# groupby and add a counter column in polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe

polars dataframe

```
import polars as pl

data = [
    (1, 3),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 10),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 5)
]

df = pl.DataFrame(data, columns=["item_id", "num_days_after_first_review"])
```

I would like to have a column that indicates a counter for each `item_id` with respect to `num_days_after_first_review`;

so the result will be like

```
    data = [
        (1, 3, 1),
        (1, 3, 2),
        (1, 10, 3),
        (2, 1, 1),
        (2, 2, 2),
        (3, 1, 1),
        (3, 5, 2)
    ]
df = pl.DataFrame(data, columns=["item_id", "num_days_after_first_review", "num"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use `.over()` with `pl.count()` and `pl.arange()`

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.arange(1, pl.count() + 1)
     .over("item_id")
     .alias("num"))
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────────┬─────┐
│ item_id | num_days_after_first_review | num │
│ ---     | ---                         | --- │
│ i64     | i64                         | i64 │
╞═════════╪═════════════════════════════╪═════╡
│ 1       | 3                           | 1   │
│ 1       | 3                           | 2   │
│ 1       | 10                          | 3   │
│ 2       | 2                           | 1   │
│ 2       | 2                           | 2   │
│ 3       | 1                           | 1   │
│ 3       | 5                           | 2   │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────┘
```